# From overlapping interval to continous interval

Tags: sql, hive, impala

I have two tables coming from two different sources, `source1` and `source2`.

```
CREATE TABLE source1 (source string, id string, value string, valid_from STRING, valid_to STRING);
INSERT INTO source1 VALUES
    ('Source1','ABC123', 'IR10', '2020-06-07', '2020-07-07'),
    ('Source1','ABC123', 'IR29', '2020-07-08', '2020-10-01'),
    ('Source1','ABC123', 'IR98', '2020-10-02', '9999-12-31')
    ;
```

```
CREATE TABLE source2 (source string, id string, value string, valid_from STRING, valid_to STRING);
INSERT INTO source2 VALUES
    ('Source2','ABC123', 'ES23', '2020-04-01', '2020-04-27'),
    ('Source2','ABC123', 'JD94', '2020-04-28', '2020-05-31'),
    ('Source2','ABC123', 'JD74', '2020-06-01', '2020-09-29'),
    ('Source2','ABC123', 'OP13', '2020-09-30', '2020-11-30')
    ;
```

I want to reconciliate the two sources to have continuous validity ranges instead of overlapping dates.
When `source1` and `source2` overlaps, I want `source1` to be considered as the main source.

The expected output is the following

```
+---------+--------+-------+----------+----------+------------+------------+
| source  |   id   | value | s1_value | s2_value | valid_from |  valid_to  |
+---------+--------+-------+----------+----------+------------+------------+
| Source2 | ABC123 | ES23  | NULL     | ES23     | 2020-04-01 | 2020-04-27 |
| Source2 | ABC123 | JD94  | NULL     | JD94     | 2020-04-28 | 2020-05-31 |
| Source2 | ABC123 | JD74  | NULL     | JD74     | 2020-06-01 | 2020-06-06 |
| Source1 | ABC123 | IR10  | IR10     | JD74     | 2020-06-07 | 2020-07-07 |
| Source1 | ABC123 | IR29  | IR29     | JD74     | 2020-07-08 | 2020-09-29 |
| Source1 | ABC123 | IR29  | IR29     | OP13     | 2020-09-30 | 2020-10-01 |
| Source1 | ABC123 | IR98  | IR98     | OP13     | 2020-10-02 | 2020-11-30 |
| Source1 | ABC123 | IR98  | IR98     | NULL     | 2020-12-01 | 9999-12-31 |
+---------+--------+-------+----------+----------+------------+------------+
```

I was thinking of using a `FULL OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT s1.id                          AS s1_id,
       s2.id                          AS s2_id,
       COALESCE(s1.source, s2.source) AS source,
       COALESCE(s1.value, s2.value)   AS value,
       s1.value                       AS s1_value,
       s2.value                       AS s2_value,
       s1.valid_from                  AS s1_valid_from,
       s1.valid_to                    AS s1_valid_to,
       s2.valid_from                  AS s2_valid_from,
       s2.valid_to                    AS s2_valid_to,
       CASE
         WHEN COALESCE(s1.valid_from, '2020-04-01') < s2.valid_from THEN
         s2.valid_from
         ELSE s1.valid_from
       END                            AS valid_from,
       CASE
         WHEN COALESCE(s1.valid_to, '9999-12-31') > s2.valid_to THEN s2.valid_to
         ELSE COALESCE(s1.valid_to, '9999-12-31')
       END                            AS valid_to
FROM   source1 s1
       FULL OUTER JOIN source2 s2
                    ON s1.id = s1.id
                       AND ( s1.valid_from BETWEEN s2.valid_from AND s2.valid_to
                              OR s1.valid_to BETWEEN
                                 s2.valid_from AND s2.valid_to
                              OR ( s1.valid_from < s2.valid_from
                                   AND s1.valid_to > s2.valid_to ) );
```

But I get the following error using Impala.

```
NotImplementedException: Error generating a valid execution plan for this query. A FULL OUTER JOIN type with no equi-join predicates can only be executed with a single node plan.
```

I am looking for a Hive-friendly query.

Comment: You should be able to just UNION the two datasets together and use the LEAD (or LAG) functions to calculate the dates I.e. valid to date is the LEAD valid from date - 1

Comment: I can’t union as I have several rows for which I have information from both dataset no?

Comment: I’m not sure why you think that would mean you can’t union? You need to treat both datasets as a single dataset, which is what a union will do

Comment: LEAD/LAG would only work if assume there can be singular overlaps, but if more than one source2 row overlaps with source1, then it doesn't work

Comment: Exactly - this will not work in my case

Comment: Happy to be proved wrong but if you have multiple overlaps then you'd probably need code (function/SP) in order to achieve this

Comment: I don't catch why unioning dates at first and then applying analytic functions would be wrong? Even for multiple overlapping periods.  Here is [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BbgOhU9d) which for given data produces correct output and uses this technique. BTW I have no idea if this query is HIVE friendly.

Comment: @PonderStibbons Actually I think this might work for me... do you think it is possible to add another layer of complexity by doing this for every id ?

Comment: @PonderStibbons Was able to adapt it to my desire by adding partition by id. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT s1.id                          AS s1_id,
       s2.id                          AS s2_id,
       COALESCE(s1.source, s2.source) AS source,
       COALESCE(s1.value, s2.value)   AS value,
       s1.value                       AS s1_value,
       s2.value                       AS s2_value,
       s1.valid_from                  AS s1_valid_from,
       s1.valid_to                    AS s1_valid_to,
       s2.valid_from                  AS s2_valid_from,
       s2.valid_to                    AS s2_valid_to,
       CASE
         WHEN COALESCE(s1.valid_from, '2020-04-01') < s2.valid_from THEN
         s2.valid_from
         ELSE s1.valid_from
       END                            AS valid_from,
       CASE
         WHEN COALESCE(s1.valid_to, '9999-12-31') > s2.valid_to THEN s2.valid_to
         ELSE COALESCE(s1.valid_to, '9999-12-31')
       END                            AS valid_to
FROM   source1 s1
       FULL OUTER JOIN source2 s2
                    ON s1.id = s1.id
                       WHERE ( s1.valid_from BETWEEN s2.valid_from AND s2.valid_to
                              OR s1.valid_to BETWEEN
                                 s2.valid_from AND s2.valid_to
                              OR ( s1.valid_from < s2.valid_from
                                   AND s1.valid_to > s2.valid_to ) );
```

Explanation: You tried to join on multiple and unequal conditions. That should be expressed in a where clause to work.